# Simple way to find max level 1 WBS and put all Level 2 WBS into array?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I can't seem to find anything about how I might do this from the documentation. My question basically has it all. I need the max WBS level 1 value as an integer, and then to loop through all its level2 subtasks/summaries and put a couple of their values into an array.

It would also be handy if I could get number of subtasks that belong to that summary before iterating so I could dim my array with the correct rows/columns and not have to transpose it after-the-fact.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, MS Project documentation is awful and the internet doesn't have much else on a lot of this.

I Don't want to have to do this:

```
Dim TopVal As Integer
For Each t in ActiveProject.Tasks
   Dim tVal As Integer
   tVal = t.WBS.Split("."c)(0)
   If  tVal > TopVal Then TopVal = tVal
Next t
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you encountered? Please show us your code and what research you've done so far.

Comment: Why don’t you want to do that? Looping through tasks is extremely quick.

Comment: I know nothing about MS Project, but from the documentation it looks as simple as calling [`.SuccessorTasks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/task-successortasks-property-project).

Comment: @Comintern Calling `.SuccessorTasks` would just move me from 1 to 1.1 instead of 2. Or if there are specified predecessors and successors(Like there are in the projects I work with), it would jump me all over the place.

Comment: @RachelHettinger I was just hoping there would be some built in function or property or something that would cut down the amount of code I need.

Comment: It's confirmed then. I know nothing about MS Project. :-D  Carry on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to loop to figure things out. MS Project doesn't allow you to pull in a set of fields (like all the WBSs) into an array without looping through everything. For this problem, you'll need to determine two different bits of information: what level WBS you're working with and how many levels of sub-tasks are underneath that given WBS.

At the main program level, you'll need to run through ALL the tasks and determine the WBS level of each task. Once you get the level you want, then you can determine the number of sub-tasks.

```
Private Sub test()
    With ThisProject
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .Tasks.count
            Dim subWBSCount As Long
            If .Tasks.Item(i).OutlineLevel = 2 Then
                subWBSCount = GetSubWBSCount(.Tasks.Item(i).wbs, i)
                Debug.Print "At level 2 (" & .Tasks.Item(i).wbs & _
                            ") there are " & subWBSCount & " sub tasks"
                '-----------------------------------------------
                '    you can properly dimension your array here,
                '    then fill it with the sub-task information
                '    as needed
                '-----------------------------------------------
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

When you need to count the sub-tasks under the level 2 WBS, it's easiest to break into a separate function to keep the logic straight. What it does it to start with the given task and work down, comparing each subsequent task's WBS "prefix" -- meaning if you're looking for sub-tasks under WBS 1.1, then when you see WBS 1.1.1 and 1.1.2, you need to really compare the "1.1" parts of each of them. Count until you run out of sub-tasks.

```
Private Function GetSubWBSCount(ByVal topWBS As String, ByVal wbsIndex As Long) As Long
    '--- loop to find the given WBS, then determine how many
    '    sub tasks lie under that WBS
    With ThisProject
        Dim j As Long
        Dim count As Long
        For j = (wbsIndex + 1) To .Tasks.count
            Dim lastDotPos As Long
            lastDotPos = InStrRev(.Tasks.Item(j).wbs, _
                                  ".", , vbTextCompare)
            Dim wbsPrefix As String
            wbsPrefix = Left$(.Tasks.Item(j).wbs, _
                              lastDotPos - 1)
            If wbsPrefix = topWBS Then
                count = count + 1
                '--- check for the edge case where this is
                '    the very last task, and so our count is
                '    finished
                If j = .Tasks.count Then
                    GetSubWBSCount = count
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                '--- once we run out of sub-wbs tasks that
                '    match, we're done
                GetSubWBSCount = count
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Function
```

Here's the whole test module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()
    With ThisProject
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .Tasks.count
            Dim subWBSCount As Long
            If .Tasks.Item(i).OutlineLevel = 2 Then
                subWBSCount = GetSubWBSCount(.Tasks.Item(i).wbs, i)
                Debug.Print "At level 2 (" & .Tasks.Item(i).wbs & _
                            ") there are " & subWBSCount & " sub tasks"
                '-----------------------------------------------
                '    you can properly dimension your array here,
                '    then fill it with the sub-task information
                '    as needed
                '-----------------------------------------------
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetSubWBSCount(ByVal topWBS As String, ByVal wbsIndex As Long) As Long
    '--- loop to find the given WBS, then determine how many
    '    sub tasks lie under that WBS
    With ThisProject
        Dim j As Long
        Dim count As Long
        For j = (wbsIndex + 1) To .Tasks.count
            Dim lastDotPos As Long
            lastDotPos = InStrRev(.Tasks.Item(j).wbs, _
                                  ".", , vbTextCompare)
            Dim wbsPrefix As String
            wbsPrefix = Left$(.Tasks.Item(j).wbs, _
                              lastDotPos - 1)
            If wbsPrefix = topWBS Then
                count = count + 1
                '--- check for the edge case where this is
                '    the very last task, and so our count is
                '    finished
                If j = .Tasks.count Then
                    GetSubWBSCount = count
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                '--- once we run out of sub-wbs tasks that
                '    match, we're done
                GetSubWBSCount = count
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I need the max WBS level 1". Wouldn't this just be the first task in your project?.. i.e. `ActiveProject.Tasks.Item(1)`

As for level 2 tasks in an array: Take a look at the `.outlineLevel` property of the task. This property tells you if the task is WBS level 1, 2, 3, etc.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/task-outlinelevel-property-project for further details

As for "dim my array with the correct rows/columns": while you could use an array and either first figure out its size, or keep resizing it as you find more elements; another approach I'd suggest is use a data structure that you can add elements to. My top choice for this is the `Collection` data type. It is built-in and easy to use, but there are others available too that may be more appropriate for your situation.

I think this snippet should do what your asking for:

```
Function getLevel2Tasks() As Collection
    Dim t As Task
    Dim level2Tasks As Collection
    Set level2Tasks = New Collection
    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
       If t.outlineLevel = 2 Then
            level2Tasks.Add Item:=t
        End If
    Next
    Set getLevel2Tasks = level2Tasks
End Function
```

Comment: Some of my projects have multiple sub-projects and all the milestones are stored at outline level 1. But thank you, this get's me a lot closer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider use `t.OutlineLevel` to sort them

Answer (score 0):

This code finds the task with the highest WBS (e.g. maximum of first part of WBS code), and counts its subtasks based on the outline structure of the schedule.

```
Sub GetMaxWBSTaskInfo()

    Dim MaxWBS As Integer
    Dim tsk As Task
    Dim MaxWbsTask As Task
    Dim NumSubtasks As Integer

    ' expand all subprojects so loop goes through all subproject tasks
    Application.SelectAll
    Application.OutlineShowAllTasks
    Application.SelectBeginning

    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If Split(tsk.WBS, ".")(0) > MaxWBS Then
            MaxWBS = Split(tsk.WBS, ".")(0)
            Set MaxWbsTask = tsk
        End If
    Next

    NumSubtasks = ChildCount(MaxWbsTask)
    Debug.Print "Max WBS level=" & MaxWBS, "Task: " & MaxWbsTask.Name, "# subtasks=" & NumSubtasks

End Sub

Function ChildCount(tsk As Task) As Integer
    Dim s As Task
    Dim NumTasks As Integer
    For Each s In tsk.OutlineChildren
        NumTasks = NumTasks + 1 + ChildCount(s)
    Next s
    ChildCount = NumTasks
End Function
```